# Javascript regex to validate if number begins with leading zero

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to validate some inputs using a regex.

Here are some sample use cases and expected results.

```
0001     - Matched
001      - Matched
01       - Matched
00.12312 - Matched
000.1232 - Matched
1        - Not matched
20       - Not matched
0.1      - Not matched
0.123123 - Not matched
```

What would a regex like this look like? If first char is `0` and second char is `numerical[0-9]` then it is invalid.

I've tried this but it doesn't work.

```
[0][0-9]
```

Comment: What about 00.1234 and 000.1234 etc?

Comment: Both are matched as well as they have a `0` as first char, and a `0-9` as a second char.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
^0[0-9].*$
```

It will match anything starting with `0` followed by a digit.

It will "match" what you call "invalid".

The test code shall make it clearer:

```
var regExp = /^0[0-9].*$/
console.log(regExp.test("0001")); // true
console.log(regExp.test("001")); // true
console.log(regExp.test("01")); // true
console.log(regExp.test("00.12312")); // true
console.log(regExp.test("000.1232")); // true
console.log(regExp.test("1")); // false
console.log(regExp.test("20")); // false
console.log(regExp.test("0.1")); // false
console.log(regExp.test("0.123123")); // false
```

Comment: You can omit `.*$`, since that part always matches

Comment: @Pumbaa80 cool, thanks! Thats specific to the test method, right?

Comment: Nope, the `.*` matches anything. So adding `.*$` to the end of a RE means: the tested line should end with...anything! It may be useful in multi-line REs where `foo.*$bar` would match when one line contains `foo` and the next one begins with `bar`. This is equivalent to `foo.*^bar`

Comment: Ah, I think I misunderstood your question. Sure, `RegExp.exec` and `String.match` or `String.replace` would yield different results when including/omitting `.*$`

Comment: @acdcjunior instead of opening a new question I'm using your answer but how can I check the value which should be total 11 numbers? `^0[0-9]{11}.*$` I tried this but not working.

Comment: @CAN what do you need exactly? This: `^0[0-9]{10}$` will match 11 numbers, where the first has to be a zero. Is this what you need?

Answer (score 4):

You can use something like this:-

```
var a = "0001";
/^[0][0-9]/.test(a)
```

Comment: This requires quotes, otherwise JS will drop the leading zeros from the number (1): var a = "0001";

Comment: :) :). I forgot to add quotes

Answer (score 3):

you can try this pattern, the idea is to use anchors `^` (for begin) and `$` (for end) to limit the result on what you are looking for:

```
^0+\d*(?:\.\d+)?$
```

Answer (score 2):

```
0+[1-9][0-9]*
```

Matches at least one zero, followed by a nonzero digit, followed by any number of digits. Does not match the lone 0.

Answer (score 1):

This one:

```
/0\d+/.test("0001")
// true
```

If "0" MUST be the first character then:

```
/^0\d+/.test("0001")
```